# How to connect NAO with Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, tcpclient, nao-robot

How to connect NAO with Unity3d to control NAO robot with Unity3D by wifi network connection. Unity will be server and NAO will be client. Can anybody help?
I have a code for NAO, but I dont know how to write Unity server script. Please help

Comment: The easier is to do socket communication: open a socket server on unity and client in python on your NAO. There are a lot of samples, and the protocol is very simple...

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are using c++ create a dynamic link library (dll)

2) Write C# client server socket program

3) Add dll to server programs folder.

4) Write Client code in unity C# script

For trying communication ; you can send string.

```
//In server
string yourString= yourStreamReader.ReadLine();
//In Client
yourStreamWriter.WriteLine("yourText");
yourStreamWriter.Flush();
```